# on() and off(), on() trigger right away but i want it to "act" like bind or live, whats wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to `bind/live` a click event when an other is done. So I'm using `.on()` and `.off()`. The way is suppose to act is that when

1. i click the `a.nav-link` a div shows up,
2. and when it does i pin a `click` event to the document,
3. it binds a click event that when ever i click anywhere in the html it close the div and off() the document behavior

now it works fine for one round but next time i click the `a.nav-link` it performs all the tasks at once, so what I'm i doing crazy here?

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xHNQ3/1/**

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#" id="nav-link">click me</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-nav"></div>
    </header>
</div>​
```

```
    $('#nav-link').on('click', bindOnClick);


     function bindOnClick() {
         $('.nav').addClass('isVisible');
         $('.sub-nav').show(function(){
             $(document).on('click', 'html', function(){
                 alert('done');
                 $('.sub-nav').hide();

                 $(document).off('click', 'html', bindOnClick);
             });
         });
     }
```

**EDIT:** what I'm trying to do here is basically that whenever i click outside the two divs the one that shows up `.sub-nav` should hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem, `bindonclick` is associated with the link, not with the document click.

```
$(document).off('click', 'html', bindOnClick);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xHNQ3/4/

```
$(document).off('click', 'html');
```

If you want to prevent clicking of link from causing a double event fire then turn it off/on too.

http://jsfiddle.net/xHNQ3/9/

```
$('#nav-link').on('click', bindOnClick);


function bindOnClick(e) {
    $('#nav-link').off('click', bindOnClick);
    $('.nav').addClass('isVisible');
    $('.sub-nav').show(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'html', function() {
            alert('done');
            $('.sub-nav').hide();

            $(document).off('click', 'html');
            $('#nav-link').on('click', bindOnClick);
        });
    });
}​
```

Comment: yea this seems to work. I thought i was suppose to `off()` the `bindOnClick` because it was that whom contained the `bind`so to speak.

Comment: does this approach unbind the html click properly? i just want to make sure I'm not making anything wrong and not best practice here

Comment: @Dejan.S - see the `off` documentation for information on best practices. Are far as this working, yes it does. Is it best for your situation? I wouldn't code it your way in the first place. Seems unmanageable as menu size increases. I like timrwood's alternate solution better. Easier to follow, less code. I'll probably get b-slapped for saying this, but worry about performance when it is a problem. Unless you have tons of event firing elements you are making a mountain out of a mole hill.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually unbinding the `$(document)` click handler. The handler is an anonymous function right now.

You need to pass the function that was bound with `$.fn.on` to `$.fn.off`. See below.

```
 $('#nav-link').on('click', bindOnClick);

 function bindOnClick() {
     $('.nav').addClass('isVisible');
     $('.sub-nav').show(function(){
         $(document).on('click', 'html', hideAndUnbind); // bind named function
     });
 }

 function hideAndUnbind() {
     alert('done');
     $('.sub-nav').hide();
     $(document).off('click', 'html', hideAndUnbind); // unbind named function
 }
```

Side note: if you want to capture all click events on the document, you can get rid of the selector. `$(document).on('click', hideAndUnbind);` should work the same way.

However, it may be better to not be constantly binding and unbinding events. You could do something like this instead. http://jsfiddle.net/xHNQ3/11/

```
$('#nav-link').on('click', function(){
    $('.nav').addClass('isVisible');
    $('.sub-nav').show();
    return false; // to prevent bubbling up to the document element
});

$(document).on('click', function(){
    if ($('.nav').hasClass('isVisible')) {
        $('.nav').removeClass('isVisible');
        $('.sub-nav').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: isn't this bad for performance and make things messy? because every time a click function is made anywhere on the site this click function triggers and i have to make exceptions in it instead of like my approach i only bind it during a period of time and unbind

Comment: From what I've heard, constantly binding and unbinding is actually worse for performance than just binding once. I doubt the performance would be a big concern as click events aren't very frequent (at least compared to something like a scroll event).

Comment: +1, good solution. For me its better with the one where i do `.on()`and `.off()` for this project.

Answer (score 0):

What is `html` supposed to do here? The second argument should be your selector.

```
$(document).on('click', 'html', fn);
```

Which is equivalent to saying:

```
$("html").live("click", fn);
```

Comment: html is the selector representing a click anywhere in the html document, i can change it to body or *

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? :-p

Comment: The `html` argument in the `on()` method limits how far up the DOM to bubble the event. In your second example the event will bubble all the way up.

Comment: i got an extensive drop down menu, so when ever a user clicks outside of it i want it to hide.